# Does Postgres create RULE automatically on some views?

Tags: postgresql

I found some random RULES in some database views that returns a SELECT which is exactly the view's select.

I did search through migrations and application code but found no definition/creation of those rules.

Does Postgres 8.4 creates RULE automatically on some views?

Comment: Yes, this is how views are implemented. They are essentially rules.

Answer (score 0):

It is [essentially the same](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createrule.html) to `create a view` or create a table and create a rule on `SELECT`. It is valid not only for 8.4, but till 9.6 inculsive:

> ...an ON SELECT rule effectively turns the table into a view

and further:

> It is considered better style to write a CREATE VIEW command than to
>   create a real table and define an ON SELECT rule for it.

Comment: emmmm ... let me check